# Select all but one tag

Tags: jquery

How can I select all but one tag inside a div. (I give a very simplified code but in the real case I could have any tag)

I have it here too: http://jsfiddle.net/yp486v9q/1/

```js
$("div").click(function() {
 $('#tot').find('*').not("h1").css("color","blue");
 // $('#tot').find('*:not("h1")').css("color","blue");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tot">
    <h1>This is h1</h1>
    <h3>this is h3</h3
    ><p>this is a p</p>
</div>
```

Comment: what you not like in current code?

Comment: Seems to works as described, but could be simplified: $('#tot :not(h1)').css("color","blue");

Comment: @Nrc _"Ii does not work. I want to select anything but h1. So, h3 and p should be blue "_ Tried `click`ing `div` at stacksnippets ? See , at OP , `$("div").click` ? `h3` , `p` appear to render `blue` text on `click` of `div` ?

Comment: I am so sorry!. The code works. It seems there was a problem with my computer

Answer (score 0):

Did you want to select all children elements but the first one? You can use the *:first-child* pseudo-selector:

```js
$("div").click(function() {
 $('#tot').find('*').not(':first-child').css("color","blue");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tot">
    <h1>This is h1</h1>
    <h3>this is h3</h3
    ><p>this is a p</p>
</div>
```